# Finding probabilities - Elementary probability.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $\mathbb P(A) = 0.3$, $\mathbb P(B) = 0.5$, and $\mathbb P(B |A) = 0.6$.

a.  Find $\mathbb P(A \text{ and } B)$.
b.  Find $\mathbb P(A \text{ or } B)$.
c.  Find $\mathbb P(A|B)$.

ANSWER:
a.  $0.18$
b.  $0.62$
c.  $0.36$

I do not understand a, b and c. Can someone explain it so I can do them myself?
I do know how I can get $\mathbb P(A|B)$ now if I got a certain $A$ or $B$ value. But that is not the case here.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I figured out now that P(B |A) * P(A) gives 0.18

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}\implies P(A\cap B)=?$$

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
and

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Comment: just to be clear a bridge sign is and or or?

Comment: Union is or. Intersection is and. "$P (A \mid B ) $" is A given B.

Comment: Im stuck with both answers and tips. If I calculate what is written I get different answers. For example. 0.3*0.5/0.3=0.5

Answer (score 0):

The relevant equalities are:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A\cap B) & = \mathsf P(A)\;\mathsf P(B\mid A) 
\\[1ex] & = \mathsf P(B)\;\mathsf P(A\mid B)
\\[3ex]
\mathsf P(A\cup B) &= \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)
\end{align}$$

Use what is known to find what is unknown.